# Using a salvaged laptop camera

Tags: gpio, camera

I was disassembling an old laptop yesterday and saved the camera. I could not find any information about the camera on the internet. I want to connect that camera to my Raspberry Pi (1 B+) via GPIO and also control it. You can see the pins and the labels of the camera on the photo below.

[image: photo of camera]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that you do with that module is potentially risky unless you have access to a datasheet or manual which tells you specifically what to do with it. Be aware that there is a risk of damaging your Pi or the camera module here.

With that said, I think the odds are good that that camera is USB. The pin designations and voltage requirements printed at the connector certainly match up with the [standard USB designations](https://www.moddiy.com/product_images/uploaded_images/patillaje-conector-usb.jpg), which are Data+, Data-, 5V and Ground. It's certainly not uncommon for laptop cameras to be connected to USB inputs on the motherboard. If it is a USB camera then there's absolutely no sense in trying to wire it up to the GPIO pins - if you want to test it you'll need to figure out how to wire it to a [male USB A connector](https://www.ocp.com/wp-content/uploads/707842.jpg).

The quickest route is probably just cutting a USB cable in half and soldering the wires from your camera module connector to the correct wires in the cable. Normally these would be colour coded as follows:

- Red: VCC/5V
- White: Data -
- Green: Data +
- Black: Ground

Per Chris H's comment below, it's a good idea for the D+ and D- lines to be twisted together for as much of the cable length as possible to reduce interference.

If you want or need some other cabling method you can look into nice easy USB A breakout boards such as [this one sold by robotshop.com](http://www.robotshop.com/uk/cytron-usb-type-a-breakout-board.html?gclid=CPfmt4uo1NICFUOdGwodr1YOLA), or shells like [this one from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1387).

Having gotten the thing cabled correctly, in theory it should be usable via the same mechanisms as any other USB webcam. We have a [great many](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webcam) questions on that topic already if you need further assistance with software.

Comment: What is with the "GPI" pin?

Comment: Good question, and I'm afraid I don't know! I'm thinking that it's *perhaps* a signal line for turning an indicator LED on the camera on or off (or something similar), but I'm guessing.

Comment: I was googling around some labels on the camera and found the chip "GL860" which is a USB Camera controller, so you are probably right. I will get into it.

Comment: D+ and D- should be twisted together for as much as possible of their length -- I'd either solder the cut USB cable directly to the camera board or leave as little as possible of the camera's wires to sodler to the USB cable.

Comment: @Scrumplex GPI? OPI? I can't be sure.  It's worth getting a meter on it once the camera has power

Comment: Thanks @ChrisH, that sounds like a sensible suggestion. For non-technical readers, USB is a high speed interface and can be picky about interference - the [twisted cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair) should help to reduce that. I *think* it's likely to be GPI (as in General Purpose Input/Interface) from some of the datasheets for similar products I looked over.

Comment: You're probably right as the GL860 Scrumplex found has a whole set of GPIO pins.  In that case it's likely to be a logic level output, which may or may not be able to drive a small LED directly. Or a snapshot button input of course.

Comment: Make sure you use an SD card with data you can afford to use and a Pi that you're OK with potentially being damaged.